# WPF mouse events update performance

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a 3D rendering application using WPF for UI. The rendering itself is done in native code, but the interaction is from WPF.

Now, I've seen that the mouse events from WPF are fired at extremely irregular intervals, and in some cases I never get any events at all. This seems to be tied to how much cpu the application is using.

By using low-level Win32 GetCursorPos and similar methods I can get better response, but this messes with the WPF UI elements interaction.

Is there a way to control the priority of the WPF message handling loop, or by other means ensure that I get the mouse events I need?

Alternatively, could I make a low-level mouse handler using Win32 calls that inject events into WPF somehow?

Comment: Just how much mouse events do you need?  I suspect the real problem is that you are trying to calculate too much other stuff per frame in your UI thread rather than utilise deferred processing

Comment: The renderer runs at 60 frames per second, but I'm lucky if I get 10-20 mouse events per second. This means that using the mouse to pan the view looks choppy even if the renderer runs smoothly. I have plenty cycles to spare each frame, it just seems that the WPF event handler gets starved.

Comment: WPF and Windows which is the ultimate source of mouse messages in an application's message queue is more than capable of delivering mouse updates that would exceed 60 messages per second.  I really doubt you are getting 60 FPS in your renderer if panning looks **choppy** irrespective of what mouse updates you are getting.   Again, it is clear that you are performing too much calculation per frame or your drawing code is inefficient

Comment: I am positive that the renderer runs at 60fps, I have debug timers and graphs that verify this. Also, other animations in the 3D scene that are driven from the renderer are smooth. It is only mouse panning by using WPF mouse events that are choppy. By timing the interval between mouse move events I see that these fire at 10-20Hz

Also, as I said; if I use the low-level win32 mouse api instead, my panning is smooth, but this messes up the interaction with the rest of the WPF controls.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with flushing the windows message queue from the native rendering layer, once per frame. Basically I call the following native code once per frame, before rendering:

```
    MSG msg;
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

This solved my problem as I now get all the mouse events that were previously dropped.

Comment: This is great, except moving and resizing the window is now very laggy (although smooth).